# XSLT select part of XML message

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm strugling to find a solution to an XML message extract problem.
What I have is a similar with below XML message:

```
<Orders xmlns="http://AU.InputOrders">
<Order>
<OrderRef>D04004451</OrderRef>
<OrderQty>5</OrderQty>
</Order>
<Order>
<OrderRef>D04004451</OrderRef>
<OrderQty>1</OrderQty>
</Order>
<Order>
<OrderRef>D04004452</OrderRef>
<OrderQty>1</OrderQty>
</Order>
<Order>
<OrderRef>D04004452</OrderRef>
<OrderQty>4</OrderQty>
</Order>
<Order>
<OrderRef>D04004452</OrderRef>
<OrderQty>2</OrderQty>
</Order>
</Orders>
```

I need an XSLT to get this bit only:

```
<Orders xmlns="http://AU.InputOrders">
<Order>
<OrderRef>D04004451</OrderRef>
<OrderQty>5</OrderQty>
</Order>
<Order>
<OrderRef>D04004451</OrderRef>
<OrderQty>1</OrderQty>
</Order>
</Orders>
```

and

```
<Orders xmlns="http://AU.InputOrders">
<Order>
<OrderRef>D04004452</OrderRef>
<OrderQty>1</OrderQty>
</Order>
<Order>
<OrderRef>D04004452</OrderRef>
<OrderQty>4</OrderQty>
</Order>
<Order>
<OrderRef>D04004452</OrderRef>
<OrderQty>2</OrderQty>
</Order>
</Orders>
```

In other words, I need to retrieve Order parts based on OrderRef element value.

Thanks.

Tried both below solution and both works.
Did find another solution which works as well. It doesn't use OrderRef but the position of the Order elements. Still this one is doing what I needed.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:ns0="http://AU.InputOrders">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:element name="Orders" namespace="http://AU.InputOrders">
   <xsl:copy-of select="ns0:Orders/ns0:Order[position() &gt;= 1 and position() &lt;=2]"/>
   </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your solution doesn't use `OrderRef` at all; wasn't that one of your requirements? Your solution only works if `Order` elements you need happen to be the first 2 in `Orders`.

Comment: That's true, but later I realized it would be better for my problem if I'll use Order element position instead of OrderRef. I posted  here the solution using fixed positions but in real life I pass those positions through tthe System.String.Format in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a fairly simple stylesheet that will do what you're asking. (It's using a default value for the parameter, but that can be overriden.)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:au="http://AU.InputOrders">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="orderRef" select="'D04004451'"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="au:Order[au:OrderRef=$orderRef]"/>         
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you need to do additional processing, replace the `xsl:copy-of` with `xsl:apply-templates`, add an [identity transform](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying), and override that with templates to handle specific pieces.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an XSLT 1.0 solution that outputs each @OrderRef group into a separate document (e.g., "D04004452.xml") via the EXSLT extension function `exsl:document`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:au="http://AU.InputOrders"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    extension-element-prefixes="exsl"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:key name="kOR" match="au:Order" use="au:OrderRef"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="//au:Order[ generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('kOR', au:OrderRef)[1] ) ]">
            <xsl:call-template name="handle-group">
                <xsl:with-param name="order-ref" select="au:OrderRef"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="handle-group">
        <xsl:param name="order-ref"/>
        <xsl:variable name="fn" select="concat($order-ref,'.xml')"/>
        <exsl:document
            href="{$fn}"
            method="xml"
            indent="yes">
            <xsl:element name="Orders" namespace="http://AU.InputOrders">
                <xsl:for-each select="//au:Order[au:OrderRef=$order-ref]">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:element>
        </exsl:document>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you have an XSLT 2.0 processor, you can use `<xsl:result-document/>` instead of `<exsl:document/>`.